# How to plot .shp (shape file) on osm map using Cloud Me iPhone api

Tags: iphone, ios, file, shapes

I have successfully used **Cloud me iPhone library** to plot routing dat on my osm map including showing current location.

**Now I want to plot map in offline mode using .shp(shape file) using cloud me api of open street map in iPhone**. But I am not finding a way to do this.

**Any help on this regard is highly appreciated and welcome.**